# Pythons equivalent to PHP's file(fn, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)

Tags: python

I want to read a file in python and put each new line into an array. I know how to do it in PHP, with the `file(fn, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);` function and it's `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` parameter, but how do I do it in Python?

Answer (score 1):

When reading a file (line-by-line), usually the new line characters are appended to the end of the line, as you loop through it. If you want to get rid of them?

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        #do things with the stripped line!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as (*In Python*):

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        ...
```

Comment: No, no it's not. `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` strips newline characters from the ends of the strings. `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` skips empty lines. Also, `if not line` is backward, and it won't work anyway since the lines all have newline characters on them.

Comment: Noted (*I'm not a PHP Developer*). Updating my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [line.replace('\n', '') for line in f]
```

Comment: That would load the whole file, wouldn't it?

Comment: ``f.readlines()`` will read in the entire file. Yes.

Comment: You don't need the `f.readlines()` call. That creates an unnecessary additional list. You can just use `for line in f`.

Comment: would `data = [line.strip() for line in f]` do the trick as well? (no need to read all lines an extra time with `readlines` and `.strip()` takes care of `\r\n` or other line-enders, as seen on windows systems, for example)

Comment: Not if non-newline whitespace at the start or end of a line is significant. Also, opening the file in text mode should take care of newline conversion, or universal newlines mode if you want to handle mixed newline types in a single file.

Comment: @user2357112 -- In that case, you could use `line.rstrip('\n')`